How to authenticate to sharepoint online using ping token
We have a REACT-based app that uses Ping for authentication. We are integrating our SharePoint Online site within the app, allowing users to access the site directly. Currently, users must re-authenticate when navigating from the app to the SharePoint Online page. We already have the Ping token generated by the app; how can we leverage this token to pass it to SharePoint Online, so users do not have to sign in again when transitioning from our app to the SharePoint page?
I have tried passing the ping token as header to to url but that doesnt work. I want to user to not log in again when transitioning from our app to sharepoint online page.
code that I have in my react app:
const openWebViewHandler = async (url: string, tokenRequired: boolean) => {
const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
  usewkwebview: 'yes',
  toolbarposition: 'top',
  toolbarcolor: '#3c4148',
  closebuttoncaption: 'Done',
};

if (tokenRequired) {
  console.log('Within open browser');
  const btoken = await getAuthentication();
  console.log('btoken = ', btoken);
  // Make a fetch request to the URL with the Bearer token
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${btoken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Add other headers if necessary
      },
    });
    console.log('response = ', response);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const data = await response.text(); // or response.json() if you expect JSON
    console.log('Data fetched:', data);

    // Now you can open the InAppBrowser with the fetched data
    const browser = InAppBrowser.create(
      'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data),
      '_blank',
      options
    );
    browser.show();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
}
const browser = InAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank', options);

browser.show();

};
